# Script data type in jquery

Tags: jquery

On jquery site it says:

"script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and evaluates it.

I get a block of js code (with no script tags around it) thru an ajax call and a chunk of mark up. For the mark up to work i need the js code to be executed as soon as it's got. Do I have to append the JS code to the dom for it to get executed or as it says on the jquery site, it just gets executed by itself as soon as it's got?

Can someone help me on this please?

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), it should execute the code returned by the function immediately.  In fact, according to the docs, there is a callback parameter you can specify, and this callback is passed the loaded script, but the loaded script will already be executed before the callback is called.  So you don't have to do anything or add it to the DOM, it will execute as soon as it is downloaded.  Also, no script tags are needed just like in an external .js file.

Comment: Nope, it's not about getScript.

Comment: Ah, OK... so what are you calling then?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, if you're using `$.getScript()`, the .js file that you're requesting will be executed as soon as it's received.  The [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) state that right at the top.

If you're requesting to some service that just returns you text that happens to be JavaScript mark-up, you're going to have to wrap it in `<script>` tags and then append it to your DOM.  Take a look at this [link](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS) - it gives a nice walk-through on how you would do this.  It's more pure JavaScript, but you could shorten some things to use jQuery if you wanted.

A key part of the article is this block of code that shows how to dynamically add your JavaScript to the DOM:

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.onload=scriptLoaded;
newScript.src = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=sunset&format=json';
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make 2 distinct Ajax queries:

- one with dataType:"script" to get (and execute) the script
- one with dataType:"html" for your content.

**But** the simplest way is probably to include your script (properly tagged) with the rest of the response. I think it is evaluated as soon as it is included in the DOM.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. But i don't see the desired output. I get the script like  "var a=1; var b= ............. call();" and then the HTML. I see the HTML appended to the DOM as well. But it just does not work since it's not able to look for the script it needs.

Comment: The jQuery documentation says: "script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Maybe this explains why you see the code. Try not adding it to the DOM. And are you sure it is not executed?

Comment: And i tried getting both as one but unfortunately jquery/ajax does not like <script> tags and it just strips them off before it is appended to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which Douglas Crockford would [frown upon](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) (see last tip), would be to just `eval` the JavaScript code you receive from the server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scriptString = "alert('hi');";  //assume I get this from the server 
                                        // as a string of JavaScript commands
    eval(scriptString); //executed immediately
});
```